# JavaScript return not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, return, return-value

I have a basic `jQuery` function:

```
$(document).on('click', '#myElement', function(){
    alert( getItemDescription('2') );
});
```

My function gets called, and runs the following as expected:

```
function getItemDescription(id){
        $.post("item_description.php", {id:id}, 
function () {
            // ...
        })
            .done(function (data) {
                    return data;
            })
            .fail(function () {
                return 'error';
            });
    }
```

When I look at the network tab in the console window, the `.post()` is successfully retrieving the correct info from `item_description.php`  --  However my original function -- The `alert` simply replies `undefined`  --  I have looked at the return manual in `JS` and read numerous posts on S.O.  --  `return` is supposed to be able to return a literal is it not?  What am I not seeing with this simple script?  How do I get the retrieved variable `data` from `getItemDescription` into the `alert` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your second function doesn't return anything at the moment, what you need is

```
function getItemDescription(id){
        return $.post("item_description.php", {id:id}, 
function () {
            // ...
        })
            .done(function (data) {
                    return data;
            })
            .fail(function () {
                return 'error';
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is call inside *.done*. One example is:

```
function getItemDescription(id,f){
        $.post("item_description.php", {id:id}, 
function (data) {
            // ...
        })
            .done(function (data) {
                    f(data);
            })
            .fail(function () {
                return 'error';
            });
    }

$(document).on('click', '#myElement', function(){
    getItemDescription('2'，alert);
});
```

also you should not use .done in this case, since data is already retrieved in previous chained call. if you want to catch all, use *.finally*